# dot product of matrix columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, dot-product

I have a 4x8 matrix which I want to select two different columns of it then derive dot product of them and then divide to norm values of that selected columns, and then repeat this for all possible two different columns and save the vectors in a new matrix. can anyone provide me a matlab code for this purpose?
The code which I supposed to give me the output is:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;];

for i=1:8

    for j=1:7
        B(:,i)=(A(:,i).*A(:,j+1))/(norm(A(:,i))*norm(A(:,j+1)));
    end

end
```

Comment: Plainly? No. SO is not a place to ask for people to write your code. Please provide a [mcve] what you've tried, why it did not work for you and what the expected output is.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. "Gimme the codez" is not a programming question, it's "do my job for me".

Comment: @Adriaan  and Marc B : it is about to calculating coherence value of measurement and basis matrices in compressive sensing framework and I dont think all of the members know that theory so what I wrote is a simple description of it.Of course I have tried different things but it was not what I expected. You can give your e-mails and I will mail that m.file for you both!

Comment: Of course not. Learn to use SO. See the link provided in my first comment on how to write a proper SO question with code included. Besides, this is a very much basic question you should be able to solve if you ever read on Linear Algebra and did some MATLAB for dummies tutorial

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - You can still show us what you wrote by not disclosing what the true purpose of your script is.  You can localize part of your script that (attempts to) calculate what you seek and you can show us what you've tried.  In hindsight, anyone reading this question would interpret this as you not trying anything and want us to write code for you.... 5 people who downvoted you share this same perspective.  I was one of the nice ones and didn't, but I may as well have!

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for being nice!! I wrote some part of the code but with some editations  and edited the question!

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - No problem.  Are you looking for permutations, or combinations of columns?  That is, would you consider columns 1 and 3 (for example) and columns 3 and 1 to be the same pairing or different pairing?

Comment: @rayryeng yeah different columns should be selected in each loop for example column 1 should be dot producted with other 7 columns and then column 2 with other 6 and so on....

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - Is there a reason why you're not using the `dot` function?

Comment: For starters: this has 4 columns and you're trying to call them until column 8. That'll get you an error of course.

Comment: @Adriaan  sorry that was a sample code. I edited it.

Comment: @rayryeng  no. my exact problem is that I dont know how to be sure that all possible cases are calculated

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - I've written an answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you so much. Wish that others were as kind as you are!

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - My pleasure :) good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng but I think there is a missing part. when we choose two columns and get their dot product then we should divide that value to multiplication of that two selected columns norms.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - Ah yes.  That's missing.  One moment.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - Added.  Don't be surprised with the result you get.  Your example makes the output all 1s because what you're really after is the cosine angle between two vectors.  Because each vector is a scalar multiple of the other, you would certainly expect that the angle is 0, corresponding to a cos(0) = 1.

Comment: @rayryeng yeah you are right. That A matrix was an arbitary matrix which I provided here. In my real work that A matrix is multiplication of two matrices  ( random Gaussian matrix  and FFT ). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian - No problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this a different way.  First, create two matrices where the corresponding columns of each one correspond to a unique pair of columns from your matrix.

Easiest way I can think of is to create all possible combinations of pairs, and eliminate the duplicates.  You can do this by creating a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of values where the outputs `X` and `Y` give you a pairing of each pair of vectors and only selecting out the lower triangular part of each matrix offsetting by 1 to get the main diagonal just one below the diagonal.... so do this:

```
num_columns = size(A,2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:num_columns);
X = X(tril(ones(num_columns),-1)==1); Y = Y(tril(ones(num_columns),-1)==1);
```

In your case, here's what the grid of coordinates looks like:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:num_columns)

X =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8


Y =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6     6     6     6
     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
```

As you can see, if we select out the lower triangular part of each matrix excluding the diagonal, you will get all combinations of pairs that are unique, which is what I did in the last parts of the code.  Selecting the lower-part is important because by doing this, MATLAB selects out values **column-wise**, and traversing the columns of the lower-triangular part of each matrix gives you the exact orderings of each pair of columns in the right order (i.e. 1-2, 1-3, ..., 1-7, 2-3, 2-4, ..., etc.)

The point of all of this is that can then use `X` and `Y` to create two new matrices that contain the columns located at each pair of `X` and `Y`, then use [`dot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) to apply the dot product to each matrix column-wise.  We also need to divide the dot product by the multiplication of the magnitudes of the two vectors respectively.  You can't use MATLAB's built-in function [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) for this because it will compute the matrix norm for matrices.  As such, you have to sum over all of the rows for each column respectively for each of the two matrices then multiply both of the results element-wise then take the square root - this is the last step of the process:

```
matrix1 = A(:,X);
matrix2 = A(:,Y);
B = dot(matrix1, matrix2, 1) ./ sqrt(sum(matrix1.^2,1).*sum(matrix2.^2,1));
```

I get this for `B`:

```
>> B

B =

  Columns 1 through 11

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 12 through 22

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  Columns 23 through 28

     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Well.. this isn't useful at all.  Why is that?  What you are actually doing is finding the **cosine angle** between two vectors, and since each vector is a scalar multiple of another, the angle that separates each vector is in fact 0, and the cosine of 0 is 1.

You should try this with different values of `A` so you can see for yourself that it works.

---

To make this code compatible for copying and pasting, here it is:

```
%// Define A here:
A = repmat(1:8, 4, 1);

%// Code to produce dot products here
num_columns = size(A,2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:num_columns);
X = X(tril(ones(num_columns),-1)==1); Y = Y(tril(ones(num_columns),-1)==1);
matrix1 = A(:,X);
matrix2 = A(:,Y);
B = dot(matrix1, matrix2, 1) ./ sqrt(sum(matrix1.^2,1).*sum(matrix2.^2,1));
```

---

## Minor Note

If you have a lot of columns in `A`, this may be very memory intensive.  You can get your original code to work with loops, but you need to change what you're doing at each column.

You can do something like this:

```
num_columns = nchoosek(size(A,2),2);
B = zeros(1, num_columns);

counter = 1;
for ii = 1 : size(A,2)
    for jj = ii+1 : size(A,2)
        B(counter) = dot(A(:,ii), A(:,jj), 1) / (norm(A(:,ii))*norm(A(:,jj)));
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Note that we can use `norm` because we're specifying vectors for each of the inputs into the function.  We first preallocate a matrix `B` that will contain the dot products of all possible combinations.  Then, we go through each pair of combinations - take note that the inner `for` loop starts from the outer most `for` loop index **added with 1** so you don't look at any duplicates.  We take the dot product of the corresponding columns referenced by positions `ii` and `jj` and store the results in `B`.  I need an external counter so we can properly access the right slot to place our result in for each pair of columns.